# How to restrict user to only certain domains with qemu:///session libvirt wtihout polkit?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, sudoers, libvirt

How can I restrict users to starting user mode vms to specific domains? I don't want to use polkit for this, but I'm not sure it can even be used for delegating access to users running executables that don't need root. Additionally, according to https://blog.wikichoon.com/2016/01/qemusystem-vs-qemusession.html implies qemu:///session also doesn't use polkit to mediate access to libvirtd running as root but qemu:///system does. I imagine I can edit sudoers for each command the user can use to access the domain, but I would like something more robust.